# Building PixelOS error: stderr:ERROR: files are incompatible: Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible: HALs incompatible

Tags: android

When I try to build PixelOS I get this error and I can't fix it:

```
stderr:ERROR: files are incompatible: Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible: HALs incompatible. Matrix level = 6. Manifest level = 6. The following requirements are not met:
android.hardware.power:
    required: IPower/default (@1-3)
    provided: 
: Success
```

I tried this but didn't work: [Building Lineage OS: Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71715234)